# Difficulty with Deserialize method in class srialize

Tags: c#, reflection

I wrote a program that does work with files like delete and update, store, and search And all customers But I have a Problem with Deserialize method in class srialize.

I keep getting the following error:

Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'

[**Project File**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eny5f09y7m1wbu5/CoustomersApp3.rar?m)

[**Video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjO2UrnvaKU&feature=youtu.be)

```
    public T Deserialize<T>(string entity)
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        var stringProps = entity.Split(',');
        var objProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        var propIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < stringProps.Length; i++)
        {
            if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.String")
            {
                objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, stringProps[i], null);
            }
            else if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Int32")
            {
                objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, stringProps[i], null);
            }
            else if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.DateTime")
            {
                var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
                DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(stringProps[i], cultureInfo);
                objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, stringProps[i], null);
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
            }
            propIndex++;
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to convert the data type when you are setting it via reflection, modify your code to include the conversion as I have done below

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string entity)
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        var stringProps = entity.Split(',');
        var objProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        var propIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < stringProps.Length; i++)
        {
            if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.String")
            {
                objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, stringProps[i], null);
            }
            else if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Int32")
            {
                objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt32(stringProps[i]), null);
            }
            else if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.DateTime")
            {
                var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
                DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(stringProps[i], cultureInfo);
                objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, stringProps[i], null);
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
            }
            propIndex++;
        }
        return obj;
    }
```